# Using Vue.js with WebComponents like Paper-Elements by Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, vuejs2, web-component

I'm making an web application (Server rendered, not SPA), but with some client-side funcionality, such hide element when other element have some value, make HTTP calls or validate some input fields.

Now, I'm using WebComponents (paper-elements and others) to make the UI, and Vanilla JavaScript (with some Polyfills, such WebComponents.js or fetch.js) to do the functionality.

So far, however, I have realized that I have many JavaScript lines to do things (such as hiding an input field if a condition is not met) that could be reduced (or even deleted) with a framework like Vue.js and expresive HTML with directives.

My problem, is when I try to use Vue.js with paper-elements, or other elements, Vue.js directives like `v-model` don't work (even the paper-element value attribute is `value` like the standard HTML elements).

I tried using `:value` instead of `v-model`, and this works, but only with a single way data binding (this is normal in `v-bind`) but I need two way data binding in the `paper-elements`, and `v-model` don't work.

An idea can be, while using a colon (shorthand of `v-bind`) to indicate one way data binding, (e.g. `:disabled="someCondition"`), use two colons to indicate two way data binding in any attribute (in some WebComponents, can be useful do this in other HTML attribute beyond `value`) (e.g. `::value`).

Someone know any framework with expresive HTML like Vue.js thats implements data binding (two way in any html attribute) and basic control structures (like `v-if` and `v-repeat`) or do the two ways data binding in any HTML attribute with Vue.js (o more simple, do v-model work with paper-elements).

I don't know making WebComponents feauture of Vue.js, because I use Polymer for do that.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with VueJs you can do
`:value="value" @input="value = $event.target.value"`

instead of  `v-model="value"`

Comment: Can I bind this in only one directive?

Comment: v-model is just syntactic sugar for: `<input
  v-bind:value="something"
  v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">` but it work only with input, if you wont to create your own v-model for your custom component , follow : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Comment: Ok... and can I use `:value.prop="x" @input="x = $event.target.x"`? I need do the same with other properties like `postalCode` or `city` because I'm using components with more than one input  (address input). There are properties, no HTML attributes.

Comment: :prop="x" @input="x = $event.target.prop"

Comment: @input is an event you can use other events like `@change` , `@click` ...

Comment: I know `input` is a event. During this week, I'll try the answer, and if it works, I'll create a new events in my components like `city-inputted`.

Comment: Keep me in touch ;)

Comment: I'm getting warnings in Vue `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <paper-card> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.` These components are created with Polymer, not Vue. Can I supress these warnings?

Comment: For other hand, the answer works:

`<paper-input :value.prop="client_id" v-on:value-changed="client_id = $event.target.value" id="client-selector" label="Client ID"></paper-input>`

Comment: Yes, I think is only in dev environment, but I have not tried with production vue.min.js yet

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do it with aurelia :

`<input value.two-way="variable">`

Comment: Is Aurelia thought as vm library and not a full framework like Angular? My app is mainly server-rendered, but I need an VM library like Vue.